# Is std::is_unsigned<bool>::value well defined?

Tags: c++, boolean, language-lawyer, c++14, unsigned

I am wondering whether

```
std::is_unsigned<bool>::value
```

is well defined according to the standard or not?

I ask the question because `typename std::make_unsigned<bool>::type` is not well defined.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There is no concept of signedness for `bool`. From [basic.fundamental]/6:

> Values of type `bool` are either `true` of `false`. [*Note*: There are no `signed`, `unsigned`, `short`, or `long` `bool` types or values. — *end note*] Values of type `bool` participate in integral promotions (4.5).

By contrast, signedness is explicitly called out for the *signed integer types* (paragraph 2) and *unsigned integer types* (paragraph 3).

Now for the `is_signed` and `is_unsigned` traits. First off, the traits are always well-defined, but only interesting for arithmetic types. `bool` is an arithmetic type, and `is_signed<T>::value` is defined (see Table 49) as `T(-1) < T(0)`. By using the rules of boolean conversion and standard arithmetic conversions, we see that this is is `false` for `T = bool` (because `bool(-1)` is `true`, which converts to `1`). Similarly, `is_unsigned<T>::value` is defined as `T(0) < T(-1)`, which is `true` for `T = bool`.

Answer (score 24):

`is_unsigned` is defined in [meta.unary.comp]/2 as

> If `is_arithmetic<T>::value` is `true`, the same result as
>   `bool_constant<T(0) < T(-1)>::value`; otherwise, `false`

`bool`<sup>†</sup> is clearly an arithmetic type (being integral). Now consider [conv.bool]/1:

> A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`.

I.e. `bool(0) < bool(-1)` is equivalent to `false < true`, and the latter holds since the values are promoted to `0` and `1`, respectively.

Thus `is_unsigned<bool>::value` is `true` (and, conversely, `is_signed` is `false`), due to the fact that `bool`ean values correspond to the unsigned values  `0` and `1` during arithmetic operations. However, it doesn't really make sense to assess `bool`'s signedness, much less perform `make_unsigned` on it, since it doesn't represent integers, but rather states.

---

<sup>†</sup>: The fact that this template is applicable to `bool` in the first place is determined by its Requirement clause being non-existent, `bool` not being an incomplete type ([res.on.functions]/(2.5)) and no other requirements being mentioned in [meta.rqmts] for *UnaryTypeTraits*.

Comment: Slight nitpick: "values are promoted to 0 and 1, respectively" is not 100% correct. The conversion rules (4.12) say that a zero integer value converts to `false` and _any other_ value converts to `true` (no 1 involved anywhere). The standard also defines a conversion back to integer where `true` will _convert_ to 1, and `false` will _convert_ to 0, it does however not say anything about what the values actually _are_. For all we know, `true` could be 67 and `false` could be 172 (that's almost certainly never the case, but according to the standard, it could be). Still +1.

Comment: @Damon Wait, I don't see how your remarks apply to my sentence. I referred to the values being promoted to 0 and 1 during integral promotion that is being applied whilst evaluating `false < true`. Nothing wrong there. No one talking about value representations (yet).

Comment: What I mean is that `bool(-1)` converts to `true` right away, there is no integral promotion to 1 involved. Any non-zero value converts to `true` right away. Thus, `bool(0) < bool(-1)` is absolutely identical to `false < true`, no 1 involved. I know, it's a nitpick... :-)  I mostly mentioned because a lot of people assume `true == 1`, and that "convert to `1`" appearing there might suggest to the unwary reader that this is indeed the case.

Comment: @Damon But I haven't even remotely implied that that's the case. My sentence goes *"… is equivalent to false < true, which indeed holds (as [reason why false < true holds])"*. I am aware that there is no "promotion" involved in converting `-1` to `true`. I quoted the very paragraph that defines this conversion.

Comment: @Damon I amended the wording, I hope the confusion is gone.

Comment: @Damon According to 5\10.5 `true` is converted to `1` (4.5\6).

Comment: Hmm, the type traits probably need a blanket exemption from [res.on.functions]/2.5.

Comment: Not my downvote (if you suspected that), I gave an upvote.

Comment: @EugeneZavidovsky: That is perfectly correct. But note the subtle wording: _converted to_. It is defined which integer values convert to `true` and it is also defined what single integer value `true` converts to. It is however not defined what it actually is (it could be any possible bit pattern). But it seems nobody understands where I'm coming from, so I'm probably not explaining well enough, or my thoughts are too contorted... :-)

Answer (score 10):

Yes it is well defined and the result should be `std::is_unsigned<bool>::value == true`

The documentation for [`std::is_signed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed) says

> **If `T` is a signed arithmetic type**, provides the member constant value equal true. For any other type, value is false.

So then if you look at [`std::is_arithmetic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic)

> If T is an arithmetic type (that is, **an integral type or a floating-point type**), provides the member constant value equal true. For any other type, value is false.

Which finally leads to [`std::is_integral`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral)

> Checks whether T is an integral type. **Provides the member constant value which is equal to true, if T is the type `bool`**, `char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`, or any implementation-defined extended integer types, including any signed, unsigned, and cv-qualified variants. Otherwise, value is equal to false.

Interestingly, there is another function [`std::numeric_limits::is_signed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_signed) that states

> The value of `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed` is `true` for all signed arithmetic types `T` and `false` for the unsigned types. This constant is meaningful for all specializations.

Where the specialization for `bool` is listed as `false`, which also confirms that `bool` is considered unsigned.

Comment: cppreference is not an authoritative source, merely interpretation. OP needed an authoritative information - the standard.

Comment: @IlyaPopov In most cases cppreference quotes the standard verbatim and notes which version (C++03/11/14/etc) it applies to.

Comment: Yeah, it's called cpp _reference_ for a reason. Unlike cplusplus.com.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is well-defined, as is any other unary type trait.

C++14 (n4140) 20.10.4/2 "Unary type traits" mandates:

> Each of these templates shall be a UnaryTypeTrait (20.10.1) with a BaseCharacteristic of `true_type` if the
>   corresponding condition is true, otherwise `false_type`.

20.10.1/1:

> A *UnaryTypeTrait* describes a property of a type. It shall be a class template that takes one template type
>   argument and, optionally, additional arguments that help define the property being described. It shall be
>   `DefaultConstructible`, `CopyConstructible`, and publicly and unambiguously derived, directly or indirectly,
>   from its *BaseCharacteristic,* which is a specialization of the template `integral_constant` (20.10.3),
>   with the arguments to the template `integral_constant` determined by the requirements for the particular
>   property being described. The member names of the BaseCharacteristic shall not be hidden and shall be
>   unambiguously available in the UnaryTypeTrait.

From this it follows that the construct `std::is_unsigned<T>::value` has to be well-defined for any type `T`, whether the concept of "signedness" makes sense for the type or not.